# How to compile pascal file without IDE

Tags: cmd, pascal, freepascal

I need to compile `.pas` without IDE on Windows.
How can I do this via `cmd`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunatly I can't found the compiler therefore I download TurboPascal. I write my code in `Sublime Text` then I open CMD and use `fpc *filename.pas*` command.

Answer (score 0):

You can't compile code without a compiler.  A compiler is software that compiles code.  There is no compiler built into `CMD.EXE`

Comment: I know it. I am looking for a way to install a compiler without IDE